# scp error: not a regular file

Tags: linux, backup, migration

I am trying to copy a directory from my local machine to a remote machine.

Here is the command I am using;

sudo scp /run/media/orcacomputers/DataCabinet/fileBackups/centos6-root/etc/httpd/conf.d​/ :root@ip/etc/httpd/conf.d​

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the `-r` option that is required to copy a directory and its contents.

From [man scp](https://ss64.com/bash/scp.html):

> -r   Recursively copy entire directories.

So your command would be:

```
sudo scp -r /run/media/orcacomputers/DataCabinet/fileBackups/centos6-root/etc/httpd/conf.d​/ root@ip:/etc/httpd/conf.d​
```

Comment: command not found

Comment: Which command is it saying is not found?

Comment: sudo: /run/media/orcacomputers/DataCabinet/fileBackups/centos6-root/etc/httpd/conf.d​/: command not found
[orcacomputers@orcainbox conf.d]$ sudo -r scp /run/media/orcacomputers/DataCabinet/fileBackups/centos6-root/etc/httpd/conf.d​/ root@159.65.66.179:/etc/httpd/conf.d​

Comment: You wrote `sudo -r scp` but it should be `sudo scp -r`

Comment: That's a whole new problem now. Run it one more time with the additional -v option to see if it gives you more of a clue where it's getting tripped up. Run `sudo scp -rv /run/media/orcacomputers/DataCabinet/fileBackups/centos6-root/etc/httpd/conf.d​/`

Comment: thanks! here is the paste bin 
https://pastebin.com/p1XtPR9W

Comment: There are a number of possible causes to what you're seeing but this is wandering too far off from the original problem: the missing `-r` option that was preventing a directory from being copied. I would encourage you to start a new post with all the details necessary to troubleshoot this new authentication issue you're seeing. It's too complex to go back and forth here in the comments on this post.

Comment: Okay great, thank you for the clarification. 
10-4 Powerhouse 0ut

Answer (score 0):

move into localhost files from server

```
scp -r root@132.93.78.55:/var/www/html/foldername/  /var/www/html/foldername
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).